# fadeIn not working after reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

The fadeIn and fadeOut work up to '#img9' after which it disappears when 
instead '#img1' should fade in again. I've looked at similar questions but I can't see find the answer.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var currentImg = 1;
    $('#img1').fadeIn(300);
    $('img').on('click', switchImg);

    function switchImg() {
        $('#img' + currentImg).fadeOut(500).delay(250, updateImg);       
    }

    function updateImg(){
        currentImg++;
        if (currentImg > 9) {
            currentImg = 1;
        }
        $('#img' + currentImg).fadeIn(500);
    }
});
</script>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="width:600px">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/Cplusplus.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="display:none" id="img1"/>
    <img src="~/Content/Images/HelloWorld.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="display:none" id="img2"/>
    <img src="~/Content/Images/Java.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="display:none" id="img3"/>
    <img src="~/Content/Images/KeepCalm.png" class="img-responsive" style="display:none" id="img4"/>
    <img src="~/Content/Images/NodeJS.png" class="img-responsive" style="display:none" id="img5"/>
    <img src="~/Content/Images/NotCalm.png" class="img-responsive" style="display:none" id="img6"/>
    <img src="~/Content/Images/Python.png" class="img-responsive" style="display:none" id="img7"/>
    <img src="~/Content/Images/Ubuntu.png" class="img-responsive" style="display:none" id="img8"/>
    <img src="~/Content/Images/VisualStudio.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="display:none" id="img9"/>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI: [link](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/06/jquery-delay-not-working-for-you/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why but removing the delay solves the problem:

```
$('#img' + currentImg).fadeOut(500, updateImg);
```

example:
http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/YWbEgN?editors=1010

(I changed the imgs to h2 tags)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I didn't really need the delay anyways. Though I guess I would be helpful to know why it didn't work with the delay.